# Django on tornado: 'module' object has no attribute 'wsgi'

Tags: python, django, tornado

I'm trying to run Django wsgi application on on tornado server using tornado fallback

```
wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(
    django.core.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
)
tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
    [
        (r"/hello/(.*)", HelloHandler),
        ('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
    ]
)
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
server.listen(options.port)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

but when I run this file, I got the following error:

```
    django.core.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wsgi'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please show the complete code including the imports. It looks like you just did `import tornado`, not `import tornado.wsgi` (and all the other modules). In python, you must import all the modules you need; you cannot import an entire package at once (although it may look like you can sometimes due to transitive imports; if you do `import tornado.httpserver` the `tornado.ioloop` package will also be loaded)